# Find all objects with a given user in Meteor

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor collection, let's call it `Pets`. Pets can have multiple owners, so I'm storing the owner ids as an array in the collection, eg.:

```
var pet_id = Pets.insert({'name': 'Spot', 'ownerIds': [Meteor.userId()]})
```

How do I find all the pets owned by a particular user?

I can find all pets where a user is the *only* owner easily:

```
Pets.find({'ownerIds':['rzfNpWfx688hkZY3X']}).fetch()
```

I also tried this, but it returns an empty array:

```
Pets.find({'ownerIds.$':'rzfNpWfx688hkZY3X'}).fetch()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the solution is easy - there's even an example in the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#selectors):

```
Pets.find({'ownerIds':'rzfNpWfx688hkZY3X'}).fetch()
```